# JIRA issue linking on issue update event

Tags: jira

We have a three level hierarchy in our JIRA instance:

> level1 -> level2 -> level3

- level 1 contains links to level 2 and level 2 contains link to level 3.
- level 2 contains n number of level3.

How can I add a link from level1 to level 3 when every level 3 is linked to level 2 using issue links?
This should be automatically linked based on events like `created` or `updated`.

FYI: We have *script runner* installed.